# #as_json includes does not call as_json on the assoc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a

```
User(id, name, something_secret, created_at, updated_at)
```

and a

```
Company(id, name, something_secret, created_at, updated_at)
```

Model:

```
class Company
  def as_json(options = {})
    opts = {
      only: [:id, :name]
    }.merge(options)
    super(opts)
  end
end

class User
  def as_json(options = {})
    opts = {
      only: [:id, :name],
      includes: [:company]
    }.merge(options)
    super(opts)
  end
end
```

If I call `company.as_json`, then everything is fine, I get:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Name"
}
```

HOWEVER, if I call `user.as_json`, then it includes ALL of company stuff

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Jim",
  company: {
    id: 1,
    name: "Name",
    something_secret: "super secret",
    created_at: "2016-11-12 13:03:07",
    updated_at: "2016-11-12 13:03:07"
  }
}
```

This seems like it should call `#as_json` on the company, but it doesn't. WHY doesn't it? and HOW can I get it to do so?

Thanks

Comment: I agree that it seems like it should be recursive since `to_json` is a recursive call but it is considered poor form to call or override this method. If you find yourself doing this frequently I would have a look at Presenters. The [`draper`](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) gem makes it simple and the representations are very modular

Answer (score 0):

You can use `only` to restrict access to associated `Company` attributes within `includes` in `User` model as follows:

```
class User
  def as_json(options = {})
    opts = {
      only: [:id, :name],
      includes: {company: {only: [:id, :name]}}
    }.merge(options)
    super(opts)
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems pretty smelly to me. If I include the company in multiple places, then I have to add/change it everywhere? Seem strange that Ruby/Rails doesn't automatically call it. I guess I could add a PUBLIC_ATTRIBUTES constant to Company, then have ```includes: {company: {only: Company::PUBLIC_ATTRIBUTES}}``` in the User model

Comment: @PeterR yes, you can do that.